# Bind9 DNS Server not working on Windows 11

Tags: windows, dns, bind, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

Guys! I am trying to set up a custom bind9 server that I can use on Windows and other Android Machines as my primary DNS (Name Server).

## Technical Details

`Bind9 Server - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - GCP`

**NOTE**: I have set up my Bind9 Server on Google Cloud Platform using its marketplace. And therefore, I wanted you to know if it can change some of the configuration, that might be messing this up.

## Problem

When I go into Windows Network Properties and set up my server address in the DNS Area, and then I do a google search to the domain webadmin.example.com which points to x.x.x.x in the Bind9 Name Server. It does not work.

But when I go ahead and do a `nslookup` without the DNS Being set to my Bind9 Public IP Address, It do `server my_dns_ip` and then `webadmin.example.com` it points to the x.x.x.x, I am not sure what is happening here.

As you can see below I have attached the images to the DNS Configuration that I did here,
[image: DNS Image]

Here, as you can see I created a master zone called example.com

Its Configuration is as follows:

[image: DNS Configuration]

The NameServer Configuration is as follows:
[image: Nameservers]

## NSLOOKUP WITHOUT DNS IP

The nslookup works fine here as seen:

```
C:\Users\Namaz>nslookup
Default Server:  csp1.zte.com.cn
Address:  192.168.1.1

> server 35.220.199.91
Default Server:  81.179.190.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
Address:  35.190.179.81

> webadmin.example.com
Server:  81.179.190.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
Address:  35.190.179.81

Name:    webadmin.example.com
Served by:
- webadmin.example.com
          35.190.179.81
          webadmin.example.com
```

## NS LOOKUP WITH DNS SET TO BIND9 DNS SERVER

```
C:\Users\Namaz>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  35.190.179.81
```

Comment: 1) Your question is not clear. You state **as my primary DNS**. Primary DNS for what? As an authoritative Name Server or as a Caching Resolver? 2) Have you opened the required firewall ports so the DNS server can communicate?

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, John! I want to set it up as an authoritative Name Server, and yes as the ports for communication are open. Namely Port 10000 (Webadmin) - And Port 53 for DNS is also open. Thanks for the reply BTW!

Comment: Did you enable both UPD and TCP for port 53? Did you link your DNS server with your Registrar? Your question lacks the details to help you.

Comment: You should not use `example.com` domain.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I tried that with another domain, it gives the same response here as well, is there any guide that includes setting up the Bind9 Server and adding it to Windows?

Comment: 1) You can only use a domain name you own/control. 2) The Registrator for the domain points to the Name Servers for the domain. You cannot just create a DNS server and host a public domain (zone). The DNS Server must be linked back to the Registrar. If you need a free 90 day domain name for testing consider https://www.freenom.com/